# Ruby on Rails mailgun send mail with API fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailgun

I am trying to send a mail with mailgun api but I always get a BAD REQUEST 400 error. The corresponding piece of  code is

```
 data = Multimap.new
    data[:from] = "Excited User <postmaster@mydomain.mailgun.org"
    data[:to] = "foo@bar.com"
    data[:subject] = "Hello"
    data[:text] = "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"  
    RestClient.post "https://api:my-key"\
    "@api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain/messages", data
```

If I rewrite the code as

```
  RestClient.post "https://api:my-key"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain/messages",
  :from => "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@mydomain.mailgun.org>",
  :to => "foo@bar.com",
  :subject => "Hello",
  :text => "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
```

it works but i want to add attachements, html etc . Am I missing something here?